# Teams Task Module URL is not loading the HTML, using ngrok url it works

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, task-module

When the user clicks an action button, the task module opens up but HTML is not getting loaded inside it.

[image]

If I use ngrok URL it works, when I replace it with the actual server URL it is not working.

Here actual server URL **domain** is the same messaging endpoint **domain**.

Messaging endpoint: https://xx.abc.efg.com/msteams/api/messages

**HTML endpoint**: https://xx.abc.efg.com/msteams/api/test

```
   {
      width: 500,
      height: 450,
      title: 'Task Module Fetch Example',
      url: `https://xx.abc.efg.com/msteams/api/test`,
      fallbackUrl: `https://xx.abc.efg.com/msteams/api/test`
    }
```

If I update URL with ngrok URL it works,

```
{
      width: 500,
      height: 450,
      title: 'Task Module Fetch Example',
      url: `https://cf6b-27-7-XXXx.ngrok-free.app/msteams/api/test`,
      fallbackUrl: `https://cf6b-27-7-XXXX.ngrok-free.app/msteams/api/test`
    }
```

If I directly open the **HTML endpoint** in the browser, my server logs show the route is reachable and the server responds with HTML.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.5.2/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <title>Microsoft Teams Task Module Tester - Custom Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
    </script>
    <div>Custom Form</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

But when the user clicks the button task module opens but route /msteams/api/test is not even being hit for the HTML page.

Comment: Is xx.abc.efg.com in your valid domains list in your manifest?

Comment: Yes it is added in valid domain. Message endpoint domain is same which is working.

Comment: Could you please share the console logs which you are getting?

Comment: Could you please share the console logs which you are getting?

Comment: The issue is no more seen, with no change from server-side code it started working. @Nivedipa-MSFT. Only I added the trusted domain again... which was the same as before.